# Plot time series with time index in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have tick time series data that looks like this:

```
                V1     V2     V3
1 01/01/04 07:43:00 1.2587 1.2597
2 01/01/04 07:47:52 1.2585 1.2595
3 01/01/04 17:46:14 1.2586 1.2596
4 01/01/04 17:56:08 1.2585 1.2595
5 01/01/04 17:56:15 1.2585 1.2595
6 01/01/04 17:56:28 1.2585 1.2595
```

I would like to plot `V2` and the following is the code that I wrote:

```
V<-read.csv("price.csv",header=FALSE)
d1<-(V$V2)
plot.ts(d1)
```

then this is what I got:

[image]

The graph looks fine but I would like to change the x-axis to Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr...Dec. Can someone please suggest to me the way to do it? I tried `strptime` and then used `ggplot2` but it doesn't seem to work. I am sorry if my question is obvious to all but me because I am self-learning R
UPDATE:
My data is quite big and freeze my computer, I just run it again and the following is sample of `dput(head(V))`:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("01/01/04 07:43:00", 
"01/01/04 07:47:52", "01/01/04 17:46:14", "01/01/04 17:56:08", 
"01/01/04 17:56:15", "01/01/04 17:56:28", "01/01/04 17:56:30", 
"01/01/04 17:56:40", "01/01/04 17:57:35", "01/01/04 17:58:40", 
"01/01/04 17:58:52", "01/01/04 18:00:48", "01/01/04 18:01:44", 
"01/01/04 18:01:52", "01/01/04 18:02:57", "01/01/04 18:03:14", 
.....
"31/12/04 20:59:55", "31/12/04 20:59:57", "31/12/04 20:59:58", 
"31/12/04 20:59:59", "31/12/04 21:00:01", "31/12/04 21:00:04", 
"31/12/04 21:00:06", "31/12/04 21:00:12", "31/12/04 21:00:17", 
"31/12/04 21:00:23", "31/12/04 21:00:24", "31/12/04 21:00:30", 
"31/12/04 21:00:31", "31/12/04 21:00:32", "31/12/04 21:00:37", 
"31/12/04 21:00:39", "31/12/04 21:00:45", "31/12/04 21:36:00"
 ), class = "factor"), V2 = c(1.2587, 1.2585, 1.2586, 1.2585, 
 1.2585, 1.2585), V3 = c(1.2597, 1.2595, 1.2596, 1.2595, 1.2595, 
 1.2595)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please post sample data.  For example, the output of `dput(head(V))`.

Comment: @ Matthew Lundberg: the output of `dput(head(V))` looks like this:`structure(c(0.119835710156028, 0.140092512643837, 0.140518613838862, 
-0.131611244573737, 0.142566044074803, 0.259392334813477), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", index = structure(c(1419130345.2149, 
1419130346.2149, 1419130347.2149, 1419130348.2149, 1419130349.2149, 
1419130350.2149), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 
1L))` and `head(V)` looks like the sample that I gave above.

Comment: That doesn't seem to resemble the data that you posted in the question.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: I just update my question with the sample of `dput(head(V))`. This data is quite big and I was running it with something else; that is why the previous output of `dput(head(V))` looks odds. Sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
V$V1=lubridate::mdy_hms(V$V1)
plot(V$V1,V$V2)
```

Note that you will need the `lubridate` package for this (which I recommend for most working with time series).

This way, not only do you get the plot you want, but you also convert the `V1` column to a date format for future use.

Alternatively if you want to stick with `base` R, you can use:

```
V$V1=strptime(V$V1,format='%m/%d/%y %T')
plot(V$V1,V$V2)
```

And it will work just as well.

Comment: @ CephBirk: Thank you for your suggestion;especially, on the `lubridate` package. This package is such a life saver for R beginner like me